# How to use lexer generated by ocamllex

Tags: ocaml, ocamllex

I have a trivial lexer taken from a tutorial (http://plus.kaist.ac.kr/~shoh/ocaml/ocamllex-ocamlyacc/ocamllex-tutorial/sec-ocamllex-some-simple-examples.html)

```
{ }
rule translate = parse
  | "c"         { print_string (Sys.getcwd ()); translate lexbuf }
  | _ as c      { print_char c; translate lexbuf }
  | eof         { exit 0 }
```

After generating the lexer OCaml and creating an executable,

`ocamllex testlexer.mll && ocamlc -o testlexer testlexer.ml`

I attempt to pass content in via stdin `echo c | ./testlexer` and via a file `./testlexer input`, but neither works.

I also don't see any logic in the generated `testlexer.ml` for reading from stdin or a file, is it meant to be included as a module in another program or consumed by another code generation tool like ocamlyacc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `main` function (in essence). You can adapt it from the other examples on that page.

Here's a full example that I wrote up:

```
{ }
rule translate = parse
  | "c"         { print_string (Sys.getcwd ()); translate lexbuf }
  | _ as c      { print_char c; translate lexbuf }
  | eof         { exit 0 }

{
  let main () =
    let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel stdin in translate lexbuf

  let () = main ()
}
```

It seems to work as intended:

```
$ ocamllex l.mll
4 states, 257 transitions, table size 1052 bytes
$ ocamlc -o l l.ml
$ echo c/itworks | ./l
/home/jeffsco/tryll2/itworks
```

**Update**

Sorry, I forgot to answer your other questions. Yes, without the `main` function, the original code can be a module in a larger program. It could be a program that users `ocamlyacc`, or not.